# Can XPath be used repeatedly, to narrow the results?

Tags: xml, excel, xpath, vba

Suppose I need to select a list of nodes based on multiple criteria (title of book, subject of book, author of book, price of book...), each of which may involve selecting any of multiple values (subject is one of Thailand, Finance, History; author is one of Bob, Ted, Carol, Alice)

The resulting XPath query can be very long, and the syntax quite complicated.      Instead of doing the query in a single pass, is it possible to do an initial query (only considering subject, for example), generate a list of nodes, and then apply a second XPath query, to reduce that list of nodes to a shorter list?

It appears to me the answer is no, since the selectNodes method can not be applied to an IXMLDOMNodeList object, which the initial result would be.       Am I missing something?       Is there a way of doing this?

[The context of the question is:       A form is presented to the user, to select criteria for a report generator.        The user may select one or more criteria, with varying degrees of detail.
Combining all the selected criteria into a single XPath query is turning out to be quite tedious, especially since different criteria occur at different levels of the tree.]

If possible, applying the criteria iteratively would greatly reduce the complexity.

Comment: XPath in vba or any other languages are just plain string. You can iteratively build a string anytime

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't what i am asking.      I mean is it possible to build a string that represents the first criteria, get the results, and then use a second XPath string to further reduce the results to a smaller set.      My question is whether you can use XPath to restrict an existing NodeList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XPath query can be applied to a single IXMLDOMNode to obtain a new nodelist using that node as a starting point, but as you have found, you can't directly apply an XPath to an IXMLNDOMNodeList.

One way around this would be to:

1. Perform your XPath query
2. Apply the next XPath step to each of the results
3. Combine all of the results from step 2 into one set (making sure to weed out duplicates)
4. Continue from step 2

However, this could turn out to be very inefficient.

I think har07's suggestion of building up the XPath using a string is a perfectly fine one. There's no reason this has to be any more complex than what you are thinking of doing. You can simply take it one step at a time, and use separate predicates for each filter.

Start with your main path (using pseudocode here rather than actual VBA):

```
string path = "/my/node/path"
```

then add the filters to that one by one:

```
if (filtering by author) {
    path += "[author = 'Bob' or author = 'Ted']" // <- build this up dynamically
}
if (filtering by subject) {
    path += "[subject = 'Thailand' or subject = 'Finance']"
}

IXMLDOMNodeList nodes = document.selectNodes(path)
```

Comment: But as always when creating executable code using string concatenation, beware of code injection attacks. Don't include untrusted strings in your constructed expressions, use variables instead, assuming your XPath API allows them.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help and comments.      Part of the issue is that the full XPath string to do this in a single pass is ends up being too many characters, and it seems to get truncated.      I don't know the limit on the maximum number of characters for an XPath string, but I believe my application is exceeding it.      If I try the string in parts, it works.     If I try the string with fewer choices (i.e. only 2 acceptable entries for 'subject' instead of 20), it works.